# how to center all the elements center in the html body with responsive

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZzxO.jpg)how to center all the elements center in the html body with responsive.i want all three elements in center of the body which are shown in the image.Am using bootstrap frame.

```html
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="col-md-4">
   <img src="img/quote.png" class="img-responsive wow animated zoomIn">
 
  </div>
 
  <div class="col-md-6  text-center main-img">
   <img src="img/main.jpg" class="homeimg img-responsive wow animated zoomIn">
   
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-md-2">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"  data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">Go to Website</button>
  </div>

     
   </div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMnV1.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this - https://plnkr.co/edit/ABOpqjxWw2ZvGiMiy53O?p=preview

Since you're using bootstrap cols, adding an offset `col-md-offset-4` will help do the job.

Comment: i want three images should be in row and the elements should be placed center of the body

Comment: If you want something that's exactly like in the image you've attached with the question, you can use 3 columns with the first one being an offset col, the second containing your image and the third col containing the button.

Comment: ok  i did the same thing but they are stick at the top.i wnt those to be center of the body

Comment: Applying `padding: 64px` should get you content to the middle of your container; make sure you don't use both `height` and `padding` at the same time. As for the button is concerned, play around with `margin`.

Answer (score 0):

You can a div class row to align the grid to the center of the page

```html
 <div class="container-fluid">
     <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
   <img src="img/quote.png" class="img-responsive wow animated  zoomIn">
 
  </div>
 
  <div class="col-md-6  text-center main-img">
   <img src="img/main.jpg" class="homeimg img-responsive wow animated zoomIn">
   
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-md-2">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"  data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">Go to Website</button>
  </div>

     
   </div>
   
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <img src="img/quote.png" class="img-responsive wow animated zoomIn">

            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6  text-center main-img">
                <img src="img/main.jpg" class="homeimg img-responsive wow animated zoomIn">

            </div>

            <div class="col-md-2">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">Go to Website</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```